# Ember rollback on deactivate hook

Tags: ember.js

I am performing rollback in the deactivate hook of route1. But when the next route(route2) is loaded, I see the values are not rolled back.

Is it because,

1) Rollback is asynchronous ?

2) deactivate happens at the same time as transitionTo ?

To give more context, route1's controller has `this.transitionToRoute()` and I am doing a `rollback()` in rotue1's `deactivate`

Here is sample snippet of rollback

```
deactivate: function() {
    if (App.Employee.find('me').get('isDirty')) {
        // It is guaranteed to be from the store. So, find.rollback is safe.
        return App.Employee.find('me').rollback();
    }
}
```

My model,

```
App.Employee = DS.Model.extend({
...
});
```

Comment: Are you using Ember Data?  Ember Model? Versions?

Comment: I am using Ember Data. Sorry about the MyModel. Editing. Version v1.0.0-rc.5

Comment: I use rollback() from DS.Model often in the exact situation as yours, and it works fine for me. The only problems I've ran into is rollback of 'hasMany' and 'belongsTo' attributes.  For those, I've had to write custom logic to rollback those relationships.